# Shuffling multiple iterators in order

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparative-review, random, iteration

I have a Python function w/ specified functionality, and two proposed approaches - which do you prefer, and why? (performance, simplicity, clarity, etc) (both use `import random`)

---

**PROBLEM**: Need a plain Python function that accepts an arbitrary number of iterables (tuples, lists, dictionaries), and returns them shuffled in the same order:

```py
a = (1, 2, {3: 4}, 5)
b = [(5,6), [7,8], [9,0], [1,2]]
c = {'arrow': 5, 'knee': 'guard', 0: ('x',2)}

x, y, z = magic(a, b, c)
print(x, y, z, sep='\n')
# ({3: 4}, 1, 2)
# [[9, 0], (5, 6), [7, 8]]
# {0: ('x', 2), 'arrow': 5, 'knee': 'guard'}
```

The function must:

1. Return iterables shuffled in the same order (see above)
2. Accept any number of iterables
3. Preserve iterables *types*
4. Support nested iterables of any *depth* and *type*
5. *Not* shuffle nested elements themselves (eg. `[7,8]` above doesn't become `[8,7]`)
6. Return iterables with length of shortest iterable's length w/o raising error (see above)
7. Return shuffled iterables in the same order they're passed in (see above)

**NOTE**: requires Python 3.7. Can work with Python 3.6- if excluding dicts, as dicts aren't ordered.

---

**SOLUTION 1**:

```py
def ordered_shuffle(*args):
    args_types = [type(arg) for arg in args]                               # [1]
    _args      = [arg if type(arg)!=dict else arg.items() for arg in args] # [2]
    args_split = [arg for arg in zip(*_args)]                              # [3]
    args_shuffled = random.sample(args_split, len(args_split))             # [4]
    args_shuffled = map(tuple, zip(*args_shuffled))                        # [5]
    return [args_types[i](arg) for i, arg in enumerate(args_shuffled)]     # [6]
```

Explanation: [img](https://puu.sh/EnEsK/784ae4ae75.png)

---

**SOLUTION 2**:

```py
def shuffle_containers(*args):
    min_length = min(map(len, args))
    idx = list(range(min_length))
    random.shuffle(idx)
    results = []
    for arg in args:
        if isinstance(arg, list):
            results.append([arg[i] for i in idx])
        elif isinstance(arg, tuple):
            results.append(tuple(arg[i] for i in idx))
        elif isinstance(arg, dict):
            items = list(arg.items())
            results.append(dict(items[i] for i in idx))
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                "Encountered", type(arg),
                "expecting only list, dict, or tuple"
            )
    return results
```

Comment: Heads up: the edit you reverted has been made by a diamond moderator here to clarify the extent of the code up for review in your question. I strongly advise you to not roll it back. Thanks!

Comment: @Vogel612 It is up for review - it resulted from someone improving Sol 1, so someone could also improve GZ0 mod or comment on its performance/readability

Comment: if you want to put it up for review, please understand that it's not allowed on this site to update the question in a way that invalidates existing answers. See also *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I do agree with others that Solution 2 is more readable with some improvements, there are also a few improvements that can be done on Solution 1.

- It is unnecessary to construct lists from iterables (e.g., generator expressions) when all that is needed is an iterable. For example,

  ```
  _args      = [arg if type(arg)!=dict else arg.items() for arg in args]
  args_split = [arg for arg in zip(*_args)]
  ```

  Here, the unpacking operator `*` works on arbitrary iterables. So one can just do

  ```
  _args      = (arg if type(arg)!=dict else arg.items() for arg in args)
  args_split = [arg for arg in zip(*_args)]
  ```

  The parantheses keep the generator expressions without actually materializing them into lists.
- It is better to use `isinstance(arg, cls)` rather than `type(arg) == cls`
- Unpacking an iterable into a list can be done using `list(iterable)`, which is more efficient than a list comprehension `[arg for arg in iterable]` that uses an explicit `for`-loop.
- This expression

  ```
  [args_types[i](arg) for i, arg in enumerate(args_shuffled)]
  ```

  can be rewritten using `zip` to avoid the need of indices:

  ```
  [cls(arg) for cls, arg in zip(args_types, args_shuffled)]
  ```

Following is an improved version of Solution 1

```
def ordered_shuffle(*args):
    arg_types = map(type, args)
    arg_elements = (arg.items() if isinstance(arg, dict) else arg for arg in args)
    zipped_args = list(zip(*arg_elements))
    random.shuffle(zipped_args)
    return [cls(elements) for cls, elements in zip(arg_types, zip(*zipped_args))]
```

Comment: A [shorter version](https://pastebin.com/YpyG2MRA), maybe shortest, for anyone interested; 42 chars shorter than Gloweye's lambda

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon For pure golfing there are more tricks that can be applied. [Here](https://tio.run/##LYzdboMwDEbveQrfxUbW1NKxHyqehHGRQrJGKyEyQStUfXYWpN34WJ@Pv7DE6@hP22ZlHEC07xPcEEaJedYbCxZzoSpfuV5dwBz1i4tmmJCchd51sa7jEgxqMrfJgAY7SprOgxCdp@ts7c3gSmcxcRbfdGhoVzrOzW7tpYMOuJewEOcrtZuGGvDIUDA8ThW8PhlKyi4pbbDkN2Jo3vmjTfjkw44jF22bdUl4KC0y/qoKSgb1441Jq/qetfSK4VABqrvigp5ZdmdYGNb0ZFEzXBg6yoI4H/H/xDCZUKsvr2j7Aw) is an example of what regular golfed code would look like.

Comment: Selected as the answer, but other answers are valuable also - selection rationale in my answer. Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 12):

#### functools.singledispatch

[functools](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html) library includes the `singledispatch()` decorator.  It lets you provide a generic function, but provide special cases based on the *type* of the first argument.

```
import functools
import random

@functools.singledispatch
def shuffle(arg, order):
    """this is the generic shuffle function"""

    lst = list(arg)
    return type(arg)(lst[i] for i in order)


@shuffle.register(dict)
def _(arg, order):
    """this is shuffle() specialized to handle dicts"""

    item = list(arg.items())
    return dict(item[i] for i in order)


def ordered_shuffle(*args):
    min_length = min(map(len, args))

    indices = random.sample(range(min_length), min_length)

    return [shuffle(arg, indices) for arg in args]
```

Usage:

```
a = (1, 2, {3: 4}, 5)
b = [(5,6), [7,8], [9,0], [1,2]]
c = {'arrow': 5, 'knee': 'guard', 0: ('x',2)}

ordered_shuffle(a, b, c)
```

Output:

```
[({3: 4}, 1, 2),
 [[9, 0], (5, 6), [7, 8]],
 {0: ('x', 2), 'arrow': 5, 'knee': 'guard'}]
```

Comment: Interesting alternative - wonder how much fancy Python's hoarding that I've never seen. It is, however, slowest compared w/ others according to my benchmark (see updated answer) - but to be fair, for most uses, it's entirely negligible

Comment: @Vogel612 Read the rules, fair enough - I'm willing to post removed edits in an answer

Answer (score 7):

I think your solution 2 is heading the right direction here. What I consider it's advantages over solution 1:

1. It is much more readable
2. It clearly shows that every member of *args is treated the same.

You might want to generic-ify it a bit more to handle more types. For example, the following has a good chance of also handling custom container types:

```py
import collections
# -- Other code ---
        if isinstance(arg, collections.abc.Mapping):
            items = list(arg.items())
            results.append(type(arg)(items[i] for i in idx))
        else:
            results.append(type(arg)(arg[i] for i in idx))
```

Which will inspect the type of the iterable and feed it an iterator in an attempt to create a new one. This version here will handle lists and tuples the same as your does. If any custom container type supports a `__init__(self, *args)` constructor to fill itself, it'll also work.

To be honest, those will probably be very rare. I've never seen one. But this is a very easy generic to support, and it's already worth it because you have the same code handling tuples and lists, in my opinion.

Keep in mind you need at least python 3.6 for dictionaries to have a stable insertion ordering.

#### Readability > Shortness.

Unless you're planning on visiting [Codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), don't do this. But if you do, you can shorten your functions a lot more, like this:

```py
f = lambda *a:[type(y[i])(b) for i,bin enumerate(map(list, zip(*random.sample([y for y in 
    zip(*[x if type(x)!=dict else x.items() for x in a])], min(len(z) for z in a)))))]
```

I hope this example makes it abundantly clear why readability is important. If not, try and figure out if there's a bug in here.

Comment: Thanks for the response; _readability_ is the one aspect I wouldn't expect (1) to lose to (2); I suppose (1) is 'fancier', but it's nearly 3x as short, and each line serves a clear purpose as shown in the explanation. Do you find [(3) or (4)](https://puu.sh/EnFem/9fe49aad9a.png) here any more readable?

Comment: Readability doesn't have much to do with "short" once you're above amateur programmer. The readability means that in solution 2, I can see what happens easily, and just as easily understand what happens. It requires no backtracking, no re-reads. I've read solution 1 ten times, and without looking up documentation on `random.sample`, I wouldn't be sure what it does. I've read it three times just for this comment to make sure I really got what happened.

Comment: Fair; [(5)](https://puu.sh/EnFSm/c9509c5ea2.png) possibly wins the "shortest" / "fanciest" contest, but good luck figuring it out in one read. Agreeably it comes down to preference; each uses Pythonic methods (`hasattr, zip, map, enumerate`) and Pythonic type-casting, but (2)'s perhaps more pseudocode-friendly (i.e. requires less background).

Comment: Yes, preference matters a lot in cases of readability. List comprehensions and related things are totally awesome tools in python (and I use them a lot), but they can kill readability just as fast as code golf does.

Comment: I've added your solution with a credit in the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177254/how-to-shuffle-multiple-iterables-in-same-order). If you found this question interesting, an (↑) on it would be appreciated, as it's been rather [controversial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389975/how-to-restore-a-derailed-question). Will keep this question open for a while more for discussion, then accept an answer.

Comment: Done for the question, but I have the same readability concerns about that answer that I raised here.

Comment: Updated answer w/ performance benchmark you may find of interest; also, change `y[i]` to `args[i]` in Gloweye's lambda

Comment: Checking for `isinstance(arg, collections.abc.Mapping)` might be more appropriate, so that the code will work for any [mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping) even if it's not a subclass of `dict`.

Comment: Good one. Added in.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an answer highlight and performance comparison of various solutions. *Note*: the differences should be negligible in practice - if otherwise, timing variance is substantial, and all are ~on par (per benchmark)

---

**SOLUTION 1 GZ0-Mod+**:

```py
def ordered_shuffle(*args):
   zipped_args = list(zip(*(a.items() if isinstance(a, dict) else a for a in args)))
   random.shuffle(zipped_args)
   return [cls(elems) for cls, elems in zip(map(type, args), zip(*zipped_args))]
```

---

**SOLUTION 1 GZ0-Mod++**: *(latest)*

```py
def ordered_shuffle(*args):
    zipped_args = list(zip(*(a.items() if isinstance(a, dict) else a for a in args)))
    np.random.shuffle(zipped_args)
    return [(_type(data) if _type != np.ndarray else np.asarray(data)) 
            for _type, data in zip(map(type, args), zip(*zipped_args))]
```

This solution is simply the first but accounting for `numpy` arrays (also `_type` should be more intuitive, and spares `random` import since `numpy` is already imported).

---

**UPDATE**: Ran a [performance benchmark](https://pastebin.com/PnqtvEbz) - results for `iterations = 1e7`, and `a, b, c = tuple, list, dict` of length 10, nested, respectively:

- **#1**: Solution 1 GZ0-Mod+   `114.2 sec, 71.2% faster than slowest`
- **#2**: Solution 2   `---------- 131.9 sec, 48.0% faster than slowest`
- **#3**: Solution 1   `---------- 155.7 sec, 25.4% faster than slowest`
- **#4**: Gloweye's lambda  `--- 160.5 sec, 21.7% faster than slowest`
- **#5**: RootTwo's functools `-- 195.3 sec`

---

**Selected answer rationale**:

- Best minimalism, acceptable readability
- Uses plain Python - no high-level libraries; easier to debug & understand
- Well-explained answer, describing pitfalls of original approach & how it's remedied
- Best performance (a bonus, not major factor)